# Is it allowed to publish an extended version of book chapter in as a journal article

Tags: publications, books, extended-paper

In computer science, it is usual practice for researchers to publish the expanded conference paper as a journal article. In most occasions, journals request a 30-40% extended version. However, I am unable to locate any such information concerning chapters published in an edited book. Is it permissible to publish a longer version of a book chapter as a journal article, and vice versa?

Comment: Are you the author of the original?

Comment: Yes, I am the author of original chapter.

Answer (score 2):

The only binding constraint, other than acceptance by an editor, is copyright. If you don't hold it yourself, then you have to depend on the copyright holder for a license or quote judiciously. This assumes that you want to include substantial sections of the original in the new work.

If the new publisher is the same as the old, permission for copyright would probably be easy to obtain. With different publishers the copyright issue might prevent it. It wouldn't likely be considered a "fair use" as it would probably reduce the commercial/economic value of the original.

You will also need to cite the original as necessary.

Comment: Its a springer book. "Springer Nature authors retain copyright of their book or chapter manuscript. The majority of book and chapter authors will sign a broad exclusive Licence to Publish for their contributions. Further information on copyright and licensing can be found in our publishing policies", but in publishing policies it only talks about Self-archiving policies.